# how to subtract one column by another excluding flag in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   code    time_diff    diff_flag       quantity
   123     0            zero            0.45
   124     5            less than 6     0.80
   125     8            no issue        0.78
   126     18           no issue        2.78
   127     28           no issue        4.78
```

I want to subtract 6 from every row in quantity except for `diff_flag` zero and less than 6. My desired dataframe would be

```
   code    time_diff    diff_flag       quantity     new_diff
   123     0            zero            0.45         Data Error 
   124     5            less than 6     0.80         Data Error
   125     8            no issue        0.78         2
   126     18           no issue        2.78         12 
   127     28           no issue        4.78         22
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['diff_flag'].isin(['zero','less than 6'])
df['new_diff'] = np.where(m, 'Data Error', df['time_diff'] - 6)
```

Or:

```
m1 = df['time_diff'] == 0
m2 = df['time_diff'] < 6
df['new_diff'] = np.where(m1 | m2, 'Data Error', df['time_diff'] - 6)
```

Or:

```
m = df['diff_flag'] == 'no issue'
df['new_diff'] = np.where(m, df['time_diff'] - 6, 'Data Error')
```

---

```
print (df)
   code  time_diff    diff_flag  quantity    new_diff
0   123          0         zero      0.45  Data Error
1   124          5  less than 6      0.80  Data Error
2   125          8     no issue      0.78           2
3   126         18     no issue      2.78          12
4   127         28     no issue      4.78          22
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
df['new_diff']=(df['time_diff']-6).clip(lower='Data Error')
```